# Is it possible to compile NASA Parallel Benchmarks (NPB) files in Linux using gfortran and openmpi?

Tags: linux, compiler-errors, mpi, benchmarking, gfortran

I am attempting to run NPB benchmarking on my RHEL7.3 install but come into a similar issue as the question asked here

[Error while building NAS benchmarks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30604776/error-while-building-nas-benchmarks)

Trying to make the BT benchmark, which is in fortran, I get the following error:

```
cd BT; make NPROCS=16 CLASS=W SUBTYPE= VERSION=
make[1]: Entering directory '/mnt/npb_install/NPB3.3-MPI/BT'
make[2]: Entering directory '/mnt/npb_install/NPB3.3-MPI/sys'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/mnt/npb_install/NPB3.3-MPI/sys'
../sys/setparams bt 16 W
make[2]: Entering directory '/mnt/npb_install/NPB3.3-MPI/BT'
make[3]: Entering directory '/mnt/npb_install/NPB3.3-MPI/BT'
gfortran -O -o ../bin/bt.W.16 bt.o make_set.o initialize.o exact_solution.o exact_rhs.o set_constants.o adi.o define.o copy_faces.o rhs.o solve_subs.o x_solve.o y_solve.o z_solve.o add.o error.o verifiy.o setup_mpi.o ../common/print_results.o ../common/timers.o btio.o -L/usr/lib/openmpi-x84_64/ -lmpi
/bin/ld: cannot find -lmpi
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [bt-bt] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving direc.......
```

However I am not using Intel MPI but rather OpenMPI, though I don't full understand the implication of that.

My make.def file has the following mpi related settings

```
#-------------------------------------
# This is the fortran compiler usedd for MPI programs
#-----------------------------------------
MPIF77 = gfortran
# This links MPI fortran programs; usually the same as ${MPIF77}
FLINK = ${MPIF77}

#------------------------------------------
# These macros are passed to the linker to help link with MPI correctly
#-------------------------------------------
FMPI_LIB = -L/usr/lib/openmpi/lib/ -lmpi

#-----------------------------------------
# These macros are passed to the compiler to help find 'mpif.h'
#------------------------------------------
FMPI_INC = -I/usr/include/openmpi-x86_64/
```

Similar to those posted in the above question.

From the error, I assume that the input parameters -lmpi is not a valid input parameter for gfortran when compiling but removing it leads to a screen full of undefined references like:

```
 file.f:(.text+0x123): undefined reference to 'mpi_whatever_'
```

Is it possible to compile NPB with gfortran? Or am I clearly doing something wrong here?
I have seen that using ifort is another option but I thought I'd ask the question before moving towards that possible solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hacking at it I resolved the issue with the following fixes, not sure what did it.

OpenMPI may have not been installed properly (was unable to call mpicc or other wrappers/comps), to fix it I ran the following commands

```
module avail
#displayed the openmpi-x86_64 module
module add open-x86_64
which mpirun
#displayed location of mpirun
```

The more likely fix was simply changing **gfortran** in the make.def file to **mpif77**